# Wrong object passed to Mailer when upgrading to laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After upgrading to 4.2 artisan gives this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\View\Factory, instance of Illuminate\View\Environment given
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by removing /bootstrap/compiled.php. Something you should do after every Laravel upgrade